# Как поменять цвет Label в Kivy Python

Tags: python, kivy, label

```
<P>:
   BoxLayout:
      Label:
        background_color:1,1,1,1
```

Данная конструкция ничего не меняет

Answer (score 2):

Вот так:

```
Label:
    color: 1, 0, 1, 1
```